# Calling an ASP.NET webform page from ASP.NET MVC application within the same Project Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects within the same Visual Studio Solution.
One is an ASP.NET MVC Project and the other is an ASP.NET Web Application (Webforms).

I want to call the ASP.NET Web Application from the MVC instead of having to re-write the whole web application in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an anchor:

```
<a href="http://address_of_the_application_that_you_dont_want_to_rewrite">
    Go to the WebForms application
</a>
```

or an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://address_of_the_application_that_you_dont_want_to_rewrite" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but for instance i want to navigate to the Default.aspx page of the web application, i tried <a href="~/Default.aspx "> 
    Go to the WebForms application 
</a> 
but it comes up with the error: The resource cannot be found because they are in different projects even though they are in the same solution.

Comment: If you are running both applications locally using the VS built in web server you cannot specify a relative url. You need to specify the absolute address of the aspx page.